# animating an object from a place to empty div of many divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to do a game the game contains wrapper with imgs and another wrapper with limited 7 places that contains choices user will choose when user clicks on img this img animates to the empty place till the 7 places finish .
how to find the empty place and this code didn't animate the img to the destination .

```js
function animateItem(elem){
  var source_id = $(elem).attr("id");
  var source = $(source_id).contents();
  var destination = $('#choice-1');
  source.animate(source.offset(), 1000, function() {
    $(source).contents().appendTo(destination);
    source.remove();
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="office-panel">
        <img src="img/screen3/book.png" class="book">
        <img src="img/screen3/camera.png" class="camera">
        <img src="img/screen3/clock.png" class="clock">
        <img src="img/screen3/compass.png" id="item-1" class="compass"  onclick="animateItem(this)">
        <img src="img/screen3/connection_plan.png" class="plan">
        <img src="img/screen3/earth.png" class="earth">
        <img src="img/screen3/fish.png" class="fish">
        <img src="img/screen3/map.png" class="map">
        <img src="img/screen3/Glasses.png" class="glasses">
        <img src="img/screen3/phone.png" class="phone">
        <img src="img/screen3/wallet.png" class="wallet">
        <img src="img/screen3/searchlight&battery.png" class="tourch">
</div>
```

css

```
.compass {
 left: 35px;
 bottom: 71px;
 width: 56px;
 margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: so what is problem in your code? or having some error?

Comment: @Hamza Zafeer not working and has no errors

Comment: Please add all nesseasary code. Especially the container `#choice-1` etc and css codes.